# '<<<' characters are lost in a field after saving to the database?

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, database

I have a field on a custom object before saving to the database as below:

`<span>>>> just some text <a class="Link" href="/55555555555AAA" >John Travolta</a> <<<</span>`

after saving to the database, when i query the field this is what i get:

`<span>&gt;&gt;&gt; just some text <a class="Link" href="/55555555555AAA" >John Travolta</a> </span>`

The three less than symbols are dropped..Any idea? why it is happening?

This is a Rich Text field on the UI..if this has anything to do with it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encode < as &lt; and > as &gt;, per standard HTML encoding. While it's technically true that the system could have encoded it for you, you should not depend on this automatic encoding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..but how come it is happening for greater than symbols?

Comment: It has to do with how the system validates/parses the text. Were there something between the `<` and the tag, it would probably encode them correctly: `<<<something</span>`

Comment: When i did the escapehtml3() on this field..it is spitting out all the html mark up on the UI..

Comment: you are correct there is no other text between the symbols that is why it got stripped off..Awesome!!