# question with custom label..how to insert "&nbsp;"?

Tags: customlabel

I have a custom label as
`<value>&lt;&lt;&lt;</value>` ,
How do i put `"&nbsp;"` between `"&lt;"`, When i do like below:
`<value>&lt;&nbsp;&lt;&nbsp;&lt;</value>`

It just shows error message as "&nbsp was referenced but not defined"..Any clues on this??

I want to add these " " as salesforce is stripping off the < symbols if there is no text..Here is the link for the original problem 
['<<<' characters are lost in a field after saving to the database?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68245/characters-are-lost-in-a-field-after-saving-to-the-database)

Comment: did you try using copy-paste from a web page or text editor where `nbsp` is displayed as a character to insert directly into your custom label?  I've done that before to get the nbsp into formula fields

Comment: no..it is not working..The problem is when salesforce is seeing three <<< symbols and there is no text..it is just stripping these off

Comment: post your code how you are referring custom label in your code

Comment: @HarshitVerma , That code is buried somewhere..However I was able to solve this by wraping these less than symbols in <i> and now these are displayed on the screen in italic..and business wants the same way :)

Comment: cant we use escape character?